# BlackBerry modal text input

Tags: java, api, user-interface, blackberry, dialog

Is there a modal dialog for BlackBerry OS (v. 4 - 6) which has a text input field?

I have a graphical application and I would like to avoid painting on it's canvas, just throw a modal in the user's face and ask for a little piece of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code:

Keep these global:

```
Dialog dialog;    
BasicEditField bEditField = new BasicEditField();
```

Then make the custom dialog like this:

```
dialog = new Dialog(Dialog.OK, "Enter Value:", Dialog.OK, null, Dialog.DEFAULT_CLOSE);
dialog.add(bEditField);
```

invoke `dialog.doModal()` from some button or menu action:

```
int i = dialog.doModal();
if(i == Dialog.OK) {
    Dialog.inform("The Input Text is : " + bEditField.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try following code:

```java
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Dialog.D_OK, "Title", 0, null, 0);
EditField ef = new EditField("Input: ", "");
((DialogFieldManager)dialog.getDelegate()).getCustomManager().add(ef);

// show modal dialog, wait for response
dialog.doModal();

// get the input text
Dialog.alert(ef.getText());
```

For more customization `net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog` needs to be extended. The following code will perform the same as the above.

```java
class InputDialog extends Dialog {
    private EditField inputField;

    public InputDialog() {
        super(Dialog.D_OK, "Input Dialog", 0, null, 0);
        Manager delegate = getDelegate();
        if (delegate instanceof DialogFieldManager) {
            DialogFieldManager dfm = (DialogFieldManager) delegate;
            Manager manager = dfm.getCustomManager();
            inputField = new EditField("Input: ", "", 50, EditField.EDITABLE);
            if (manager != null) {
                manager.insert(inputField, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getInputText() {
        return (inputField == null) ? "" : inputField.getText();
    }
}
```

**Exmaple Usage:**

```
InputDialog seaerchDialog = new InputDialog();
// show modal dialog, wait for response
seaerchDialog.doModal();        
// get the input text
Dialog.alert(seaerchDialog.getInputText());
```